# Sidebar enhancement extension like for sublime text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a plugin that enhance the explorer context menu like the Side​Bar​Enhancements package for sublime?

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements

I found the default one rather lacking in feature, just like vanilla sublime is.

left : VScode | Right : Sublime with SBE plugin

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think the one that gets closer to this is the file utils extension. Download it in vscode by search for file utils. This is their github repo https://github.com/sleistner/vscode-fileutils